# Image of the cuspidal subgroup of J_0(N) in J_1(N)

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let N be a prime integer. We know that the element $c=(0)-(\infty)$ generates the torsion subgroup of $J_0(N)$ and it has order Num( (N-1)/12). Now, there is a natural map $\pi^*:J_0(N) \rightarrow J_1(N)$, coming from the covering map $\pi:X_1(N) \rightarrow X_0(N)$. My question is what is the image of c under this map? Specifically, is it possible for $\pi^*(c)=0$?

Comment: This can be made "explicit" in the special case $N=11$, for which both curves have genus 1. By moduli interpretation of cusps, $X_1(p)$ has $p-1$ geometric cusps:  $(p-1)/2$ are rational points (the $p$-gon cusps) and $(p-1)/2$ are a single Galois orbit (the $1$-gon cusps, residue field $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p)^+$). Making $X_1(11)$ an elliptic curve using a rational cusp and $X_0(11)$ an elliptic curve using its image (the cusp $0$, not $\infty$!!), the deg-5 map $\pi$ has kernel given by the rat'l cusps: $\ker \pi = \mathbf{Z}/(5)$. Hence, dual map has kernel $\mu_5$, and $\mu_5(\mathbf{Q})=1$.

Comment: Thanks! This example was actually confusing me, and that clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact you mention about $(0) - (\infty)$ generating the torsion subgroup of $J_0(N)$ is Theorem 1 (Ogg's conjecture) on the first page of Mazur's paper "The Eisenstein Ideal". I recommend you actually read this paper. If you get as far as page 2, you will find a "Theorem 2 (twisted Ogg's conjecture)" which concerns the Shimura subgroup $\Sigma$. The construction of this subgroup *essentially* identifies it with the kernel of $J_0(N) \rightarrow J_1(N)$, and Proposition 11.6 of *ibid*. shows that $\Sigma$ is of multiplicative type, so BCnrd's remarks apply to the general case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think pi^*(c) can be 0.  Suppose pi^*(c) = div(f); then f would be a map from X_1(N) to P^1 of degree about N.  But in fact any such map is of degree at least ~N^2, i.e. the gonality of X_1(N) is bounded below by a constant multiple of N^2.  This was proved independently by Zograf ("Small eigenvalues of automorphic Laplacians in spaces of cusp forms") and Abramovich [("A linear lower bound on the gonality of modular curves.")](http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/1996/20/1005.extract)

**Update**:  As Kevin points out in comments I should say  "for N large enough."  But "large enough" is effective here since the constants in the gonality bounds are effective (albeit small.)

Comment: It's zero when $N=2$, right? So maybe you mean "...can be zero for $N$ suff large" or something.